# Dynamical map size in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

How do i set size in 100% for map on page that using jquery mobile?
So far i tried to set height:100%, but that didnt effect, and i still have scroll bars.

If i use height:auto, my map doesnt show

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:90%; position:absolute; top:121px;"  ></div>
```

Comment: Could we have some code example on jsfiddle or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting scroll due to body margin. Just make it 0. I have tested following in firefox

```
<html>
<body style="margin:0;">
     <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; background-color: black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont have body margin, and still scrill bar appears

Comment: You have some margin by default. Have you made it 0?

Comment: @sannySin Give my code a try. This is about div, height, margin and scroll. First you should be sure about this html. Then do the same with your actual page.

Comment: ye, i tried, that didnt work. I guess some of jquery mobile styles makes this issue

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem with 100% sizing is that the percentage is of the parent element, so that needs to have a size as well (it can be 100%).  See [this page](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm) on Mike Williams' v2 tutorial (the same concept applies to v3).

You didn't provide any context above the map div.

Comment: I tried to add 100% height to both body&html, but both didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just get the height of device and use that...

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
```